# Remove img-element from Angular page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, element, angular-directive

I'm creating an angular web app in which I want to show an image at first, but when you click on a button, I want to remove this default image and replace it with a videostream of the webcam. But so far, removing the image - element remains hard...

```
angular.module('qrWebapp').directive('qrScanner', ['$timeout', 'openScannerService', function($timeout, openScannerService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngSuccess: '&ngSuccess',
      ngError: '&ngError',
      ngVideoError: '&ngVideoError'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var isOpen;
      var onlyOpenOnce = 0;

      var image = document.createElement('img');
      image.setAttribute('id', 'defaultImage');
      image.setAttribute('src', 'assets/images/defaultimage.png');
      image.setAttribute('width', '400');
      image.setAttribute('height', '300');
      image.setAttribute('alt', 'defaultimage');

      scope.$on('handlePublish', function() {
        isOpen = openScannerService.sharedBoolean;

        if(isOpen){
        //some code
           //finding the image on the angular page    
           var findedElement = angular.element('#defaultImage');
           findedElement.remove();

           var context;

           if(onlyOpenOnce < 1){
             angular.element(element).append(video);
             angular.element(element).append(canvas);
             context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
           }

           onlyOpenOnce++;
    } 
    else {

      angular.element(element).append(image);
    }
  });
}
  };

}]);
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try to remove that DOM wise. Instead use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) that conditionally renders elements on your page.

For e.g., in your HTML

```
    <img id="imgID" src="assets/images/defaultimage.png" ng-if="renderImage" />
    <canvas ng-if="renderCanvas"></canvas>
```

and then in your directive:

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.renderImage = false; // Renders image by default
        scope.renderCanvas = true; // Renders Canvas by default

        scope.$on('handlePublish', function() {
            scope.renderImage = false; // The image element will be removed from the DOM
            scope.renderCanvas = true; // The canvas element will be rendered in the DOM
        }
```

Comment: It worked, but I only used the ng-if for the image, not for the canvas. I used also a service to adjust this value. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Glad it Helped. Do select it as the answer if it best fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

i used property `setAttribute(src, "")`

```
removerImg(){
    console.log('Removiendo..');
    let im = document.getElementById('preview').setAttribute('src' , '../../../../../assets/img/no-image.jpg');      
}
```